# ASP.NET Core ClaimsPrincipal with multiple ClaimsIdentity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I am quite new to asp.net core (2.1) and trying to build an mvc application with local user accounts. The application uses the Identity framework and a local sql server db with the [default schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2). What I am trying to achieve is a claims based system where a user can have multiple sets of distinct claims. From what I have read the asp.net classes would be able to a accommodate this because a user is represented by a ClaimsPrincipal class which can contain multiple ClaimsIdentity and Claims are created for a ClaimsIdentity. The underlying database schema does not seem to accommodate this however because while it can store users (dbo.AspNetUsers) and users' claims (dbo.AspNetUserClaims) it does not seem to store any data regarding which identity the claim is related to? Have I misunderstood the purpose of the different underlying classes or is there an inbuilt way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: A claims principal _does_ support multiple claims identities but there is nothing that forces you to use it like that. It is very common to have only a single identity which can combine claims from multiple sources at the same time. So when using Identity, you could store additional claims in the user claims database, or you could even dynamically add them from another source as the user logs in.

Comment: @poke thanks for the reply. Essentially what I need is for a user to be able to login and choose an identity which has a set of claims attached to it. For that session authorisation is based on that identity and its claims. However, if the user logs out and logs in again they may choose another identity which then would have a different set of claims. I could obviously achieve this by insisting the user has separate user accounts for each identity but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: That sounds more like you would want to sign in to different user accounts, using the same credentials. Such a scenario isn’t supported out of the box and you would have to implement that yourself. If the underlying identity (the user object) is the same, you could solve this by just adding to the default claims depending on what choice the user makes.

Comment: So from your understanding what is the purpose of a ClaimsPrincipal having multiple ClaimsIdentity and the claims being attached to the ClaimsIdentity? How are you supposed to persist in the underlying database not just the claim and the user it is linked to but the identity it is linked to also?

Comment: The purpose is for external providers who can provide the app with a user identity and set of user claims. The default model the identity scaffold uses isn't meant to manage multiple identities. Hence why there is no `AspNetUserClaimsIdentity` table.

Comment: _“what is the purpose of a ClaimsPrincipal having multiple ClaimsIdentity”_ – `ClaimsPrincipal` and `ClaimsIdentity` are actually a rather old thing in the .NET ecosystem that isn’t specific to the web. It has been around for a long time and is used in a large number of different scenarios. In some of those having multiple separate identities is more common. In a web context in ASP.NET Core, you will usually have only a single identity although the framework technically supports multiple identities.

Comment: OK thanks both, your comments have been very helpful. Looks like I am going to have look into building a more customised auth process.